# Change OpenLayers 3 script into OpenLayers 2.13

Tags: javascript, openlayers, pgrouting, html

I want to change the code from pgrouting latest workshop which is used the OpenLayers 3 beta to OpenLayers 2.13. The code is in here http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/ol3_client.html

I tried to change it, but still have got some errors like this one: `startpoint.getPosition is not a function`

Is there anyone could help me? Because there are some features in OpenLayers 2.13 which are not (yet) supported in the Ol3js. My idea is simple, I just want to have a Layerswitcher button, and adds radio button for start and final location for the route, and the compute route button, so that the web will look more neat.

Comment: It might  make sense to start from OL2 code, e.g. http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/wiki/WorkshopOL2.html

Answer (score 1):

as user underdark already mentioned there are also versions of the pgrouting workshop online that used OpenLayers 2.x

You could for example download a slightly newer version of the workshop at https://github.com/pgRouting/workshop/releases/tag/v0.6.1 which uses OpenLayers 2.10
Here you can see a part of the demo-app:

```
function pgrouting(store, layer, method) {
         if (layer.features.length == 2) {
             // erase the previous route
             store.removeAll();

             // transform the two geometries from EPSG:900913 to EPSG:4326
             var startpoint = layer.features[0].geometry.clone();
             startpoint.transform(epsg_900913, epsg_4326);
             var finalpoint = layer.features[1].geometry.clone();
             finalpoint.transform(epsg_900913, epsg_4326);

             // load to route
             store.load({
                 params: {
                     startpoint: startpoint.x + " " + startpoint.y,
                     finalpoint: finalpoint.x + " " + finalpoint.y,
                     method: method
                 }
             });
         }
    }
```

( see https://github.com/pgRouting/workshop/blob/foss4g2011/web/routing-final.html )